# I want to gulp concat the same file multiple times but {'nounique': true} is not working

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

I want to use gulp to concat some html files in order, and some of them are duplicates.

For example:

```
gulp.task('Generate HTML', function(cb) {
  const srcset = [
    'header.html',
    'content.html',
    'section2.html',
    'banner-cat.html',
    'section3.html',
    'banner-cat.html',
    'section4.html',
    'content.html',
    'content.html',
    'banner.html',
    'footer.html'
  ];

  gulp.src(srcset, {'allowEmpty': true, 'nounique': true, 'nosort': true})
    .pipe(concat('index.html'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
    
  cb();
});
```

I found the options `no-unique` and `no-sort` in the [documentation](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/src/) so I thought that would solve my problem, however I am not getting the desired result, as every html snippet is only `concat`-ed one time, so any duplicated snippets will only show up once.

Please help me with any advice or if you know any other gulp package that can help me achieve this desired outcome using gulp and javascript

Answer (score 1):

`gulp.src` treats its argument as a list of glob patterns rather than file paths. Each pattern could match one or multiple files or none at all, and if the same file is matched by multiple patterns, it's up to the implementation to decide what to do.

It's better here to load each file individually and then join the streams.

To use [merge2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge2), install the package with:

```
npm install -D merge2
```

Then your code could look like this:

```js
const merge2 = require('merge2');

gulp.task('Generate HTML', function(cb) {
  const srcset = [
    'header.html',
    'content.html',
    'columns-left.html',
    'columns-right.html',
    'columns-left.html',
    'columns-right.html',
    'banner.html',
    'content.html',
    'content.html',
    'banner.html',
    'footer.html'
  ];

  const streams = srcset.map(src => gulp.src(src));
  merge2(...streams)
    .pipe(concat('generated-page.html'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
    
  cb();
});
```

Comment: I used merge2 instead to be able to control the ordering of the streams, so that the html snippets appear in the correct order

Comment: @Solène Good find :) Yes, merge2 is the right choice here to join the streams sequentially.